# How to provide focus to a Window (Excel) using Python

Tags: python, excel, sap-gui

I need to activate a window (make it the foreground window and give it the focus to manipulate) via SAP GUI Scripting. I have automated SAP GUI execution with a Python script. For this module SAP GUI does not do the typical file name and location for the file instead it just outputs it into Excel. I want to shift screens from the SAP GUI to the Excel file and just save it to a path and certain name that is it. Then I can use the rest of my script to manipulate the file from the location I save.

I have tried using win32.com client and reviewed a bunch of forums for SAP GUI and Python but nothing shows how the transition of activating is done from SAP GUI to Excel.

All the lines I have inputted after these crash the code not being recognized or so.

```
SAP = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI').GetScriptingEngine
print "T-CODE SECTION CLEAR"
session = SAP.FindByID('ses[0]')
print "T-CODE SECTION CLEAR"
xlapp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")


##START IP24 TRANSACTIONS
session.StartTransaction(Transaction="IP24") 
print "T-CODE SECTION CLEAR"

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEQUNR-LOW").text = "fcsmon*"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtIWERK-LOW").text = "2206"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey (8)

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press()

session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[5]").select()

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
```

Comment: I don't think a solution like this will never work properly. You can't control 3rd party software. It will work for user A for a week but not for user B, C ... (other PC's, other configuration). Next month Windows release an update, Excel behavior change and it will not work at all again ... and you'll be in trouble because the user will say "I didn't change nothing. Last week it was working fine."

Comment: i dont necessarily disagree but if there is a way to use python to shift focus on the active window, i start it with SAP but how do I shift to the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save something as a excel file you can use the csv library

`import csv
with open("file", "a") as f:
     f = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
     f.writerow(["blablabla", "blablabla"])`

Comment: thanks Barty. i am able to do the saving what i need to do is make the excel file that pops up become the active window from the SAP window.

Comment: You could use `import os
os.startfile('C:\\myprogram.exe')`